# Pyplot: Circle class: What are the units of the axis arg?

Tags: matplotlib

What units does Pyplot use for the radius size of Circle class objects? Playing around with it, it seems that a radius of .6 is already almost off the screen... small example below

```
import matplotlib as plt
plt.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
circle = plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.6, color='white')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplot
plt.axis('off')
ax.add_artist(circle)
fig.set_facecolor("black")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute units are used for the radius. The reason why 0.6 goes out of the axis is that by default, if you just plot a blank figure, its extent is from 0 to 1. For example

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

results in

[image]

Now if you center your circle at (0.5, 0.5) and use  radius of 0.6, it will go outside the axis and you will see a truncated patch as you see in your question.

Things become clear when you remove `plt.axis('off')` and use **radius=0.5**

```
circle = plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.5, color='blue')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3))
# plt.axis('off') <--- commented out
ax.add_artist(circle)
fig.set_facecolor("gray")
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.plot([0.5], [0.5], 'ro')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down!